# How do I remove a certain HTML code from a certain website?

Tags: google-chrome, html, google-chrome-extensions, code

There are some websites which refresh themselves in a very short period. I want to disable this behavior.

The code that causes this problem is almost always following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180"/>
```

I learned that some browser extensions can be used for this purposed; I was suggested to use Firebug. I installed it, but it became a little confusing to me.

Can you please instruct me how to remove the line above from "http://www.example.com" with Firebug (or with a different extension maybe)?

(My browser is Google Chrome.)

Comment: Use Javascript DOM manipulation in Firebug console to remove that element.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6376/is-it-possible-to-block-websites-from-refreshing-themselves

Comment: you open firebug, find the line that you knwo makes the apge refresh in the DOM section, highlight it. DELETE. done. but only for that one page view- not forever.. ok

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey) ( or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) if you're a Chrome user)

Comment: But how? It is probably done with a very tiny script code, but I don't know anything about script writing.